# Неверная передача параметра в метод

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Заметил, что у меня неправильно передается один из параметров функции:

```
class M_Init
{
    //...
    jmp_stub* SetClosure(void * from, void* to);
    //...

}
```

Реализация:

```
jmp_stub *M_Init::SetClosure(void *from, void *to)
{
    jmp_stub stub = new jmp_stub();
    stub->arg = (size_t)to;                          /// size_t
    //...
}
```

Я вызываю этот метод так:

```
this->SetClosure((void*)PrWrkr, (void*)&_Initialize);
```

где `_Initialize` - это функция:

```
void* __stdcall _Initialize(LPVOID arg, LPVOID func) {/**/}
```

Например, ее адрес в отладчике до передачи `0x0f2715c0`, а после - уже `0x0f26182a`. Приложил на всякие случай скрины:

[image: До]

[image: После]

При чем первый параметр передается верно. Я отметил красным, как меняется передаваемый параметр (на первом скрине немного смазанный, но в окне интерпретации все четко видно). Переключаюсь через стэк вызовов внутрь метода - а там уже другое значение. **Как такое может быть?**

Comment: (Закрывая глаза на передачу адреса функции как `void *`) Отладчик вам ясно пишет, что оба адреса - правильные. Это просто какие-то разные детали реализации импорта функции из DLL. Передается и получается, разумеется, один и тот же адрес `0x0f26182a`, а то, что вам пишет отладчик, к фактически передаваемому значению никакого отношения не имеет. Не надо разглядывать эти тултипы отладчика и делать из никак какие-то сюрреалистические выводы.

Comment: У вас в вопросе написано: "Заметил, что у меня неправильно передается один из параметров функции". В чем выражается эта "неправильность"? В разглядывании всплывающих тултипов от отладчика или в чем-то другом? Если в "разглядывании", то просто перестаньте их разглядывать. Если в чем-то другом - то потрудитесь описать проблему в деталях.

Comment: @AnT ну вообще я больше ориентировался на окно интерпретации. Оно меня никогда не обманывало. Тултипы для форума заскриншотил. Ну и по факту. Первый адрес - верный, я его много раз сверял непосредственно в памяти. А в функцию передается неверный, и из-за этого далее ловлю ошибки

Comment: Проблема, возможно, заключается в том, что на импортирующей стороне `_Initialize` физически является внутренней переменной-указателем на функцию. Применяя оператор `&` к `_Initialize` вы получаете адрес этой переменной-указателя, а не адрес функции. Вы пробовали убрать нафиг этот `&`, т.е. передавать `(void *) _Initialize`?

Comment: Что такое вообще `_Initialize`? Почему в вопросе не приведено объявление этой сущности? Может это вообще явно объявленная переменная?

Comment: @AnT, _Initialize - это функция, сомнений нет. Если жать по ней F12, то перейду к ее определению: `void* __stdcall _Initialize(LPVOID arg, LPVOID func);`. И в видимых переменных одноименных переменных нет. Но, вероятно, ваша мысль имеет основания: в окне интерпретации `_Initialize` и `&_Initialize` мне возвращают одинаковый адрес. Такое может быть?

Comment: Такое *должно* быть. Для функции что с `&`, что без `&` - без разницы.

Comment: @AnT, ясно. Я всегда думал, что к адресу функции надо обращаться через &, как к адресу переменной, и это работало - думал, что это единственный вариант. Это с какого-то стандарта началось или всегда так было?

Comment: @Ant, но на этом история не заканчивается. Пусть так и так можно, значит ошибка была не в этом. Я несколько изменил код для эксперимента, и ввел промежуточную переменную adress_of_func :  `void* adress_of_func = _Initialize; this->SetClosure((void*)PrWrkr, adress_of_func); ` - прописал _Initialize без & на всякий случай, как вы советовали. Так вот смотрю значение после присвоения `adress_of_func = _Initialize` значение `adress_of_func` не совпадает ни с _Initialize, ни с &_Initialize. Ну вроде же правильно делаю?

Comment: @Ant, сделал проверку адреса через MessageBox - адреса совпадают. Значит меня обманывает отладчик. Жаль. Я так на него надеялся, что легче будет проекты отлаживать без постоянной перекомпиляции с новыми MessageBox-ами и cout-ами (((

Comment: @Ant, нет, все равно дело нечисто. Пусть местами обманывал дебаггер. Но то значение, которым он обманывал оказалось верным. А присвоенное реальное значение - нет

Comment: Минусуют те, кто не могут. Даже в вопрос по любому не вникли

Comment: При чем разница между адресами постоянно фиксированная - 64918 байт

Comment: Между разными функциями разная. Другую взял - тоже отличаются - 66140 байт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Скорее всего, это был глюк отладчика vs2017. Ее корень, по моим наблюдениям, был в том, что отладка происходила из под проекта dll, который вызывался exe-приложением. В проекте самого exe, который вызывал эту библиотеку **при последовательном трассировании, отладчик все показывал правильно**. Но если просто расставить брейкпойнты без последовательных шагов с заходом, происходит тоже нечто описанное в шапке.

Скомпилированное приложение работало верно.

Большое спасибо всем кто заминусовал. Видимо, это специалисты высокого класса, которые сталкивались с подобной проблемой и заведомо знали ее решение, но пояснений от которых я был недостоен